# Problem with inserting into MySQL database from Python

Tags: python, mysql, macos, terminal

I am having trouble inserting a record into a MySQL database from python. This is what I am doing.

```
def testMain2():
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(charset='utf8', host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="epf")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        tableName = "test_table"

        columnsDef = "(export_date BIGINT, storefront_id INT, genre_id INT, album_id INT, album_rank INT)"
        exStr = """CREATE TABLE %s %s""" % (tableName, columnsDef)
        cursor.execute(exStr)

        #Escape the record
        values = ["1305104402172", "12", "34", "56", "78"]                    
        values = [conn.literal(aField) for aField in values]

        stringList = "(%s)" % (", ".join(values))
        columns = "(export_date, storefront_id, genre_id, album_id, album_rank)"
        insertStmt = """INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s""" % (tableName, columns, stringList)
        cursor.execute(insertStmt)

        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

The table is created however nothing is in the table. I can run the `INSERT` statement successfully in Terminal with the same credentials.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: post output here of insertStmt variable

Comment: Excuse me? Are you saying that printing insertStmt (not output of query exec) results in no output?

Comment: if that's the case then stringlist may be the culprit; can you print stringlist? Not a pythonista, you may want to post under python tag, this is likely a no brainer for experienced python user (apologies if that is you!)

Comment: et voila, @Dan, experienced python user to the rescue

Comment: I don't get any outputs or an error when I run the above code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't committed the transaction.

```
conn.commit()
```

(The MySQLdb library sets `autocommit` to False when connecting to MySQL. This means that you need to manually call commit or your changes will never make it into the database.)